# Base table or view already exists

Tags: field, mysql

Getting the following error on production environment when trying to add a new Field.

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'redacted' already exists

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is it a Matrix field you're trying to add and is the handle `redacted`? If so, does a table named `redacted` already exist in the database?

Comment: Hey @BradBell, 

Just a regular Plain Text field (not Matrix). I just put "redacted" in there because the table contained info that made the hosting environment evident. It actually says:

Table '[name-of-hosting-provider]/#sql-ib450' already exists.

Not sure what the 'sql-ib450' is all about.

Comment: Weird... can you enabled devMode then share the full stack trace leading up to the error?  Wondering if a plugin is getting involved.  Craft won't create a new table for a Plain Text field.

Comment: Sure thing @BradBell - where will I find the log you are looking for? This is on production so I want to limit the time the [devMode] is in the title tags.

It's worth noting that I CANNOT replicate this issue on my local or development environments.

Comment: You could conditionally enable devMode from your IP address in `craft/config/general.php`... something like `if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '1.2.3.4') { 'devMode' => true }`

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be an issue with the mysql server itself, not a Craft CMS issue at all.

It appears that during a previous field addition, the database server crashed and left hanging temporary files that didn't match with the database itself.

Spun up a new database, copied the DB over and everything worked as expected.